# Wrong language detected when using Javascript navigate method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator

I 'm building a React JS website and got stuck on an issue relater to the navigator problem.
My default browser is Chrome and using English as a language. When I log navigator.language it gives me "he-IL", which I do use but not as default language. In the navigator.languages i get the following array:["he-IL", "en-US", "en", "he"].

Is there a way to set it to detect English only when using navigator.language?
Or do I have to get it from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the default language being used at the navigator function is user-specific, it returns an array of DOMStrings representing the user's preferred languages. You tried returning the array list of languages associated?. In the returned array they are ordered by preference with the most preferred language first.

The property can be changed easily by changing the browser settings. Currently, I think your default is he-IL, so need to change the default to English.

Mine works fine and the

> navigator.languages returns ["en-US", "zh-CN", "ja-JP"]

Comment: To change the language to preferred ones:  Open the browser settings and the Content tab. Under the Languages heading, choose your preferred language(s) by selecting the language or language+region combination you want from the list provided. Then adjust the order to indicate your order of preference

Comment: Well the navigator.languages array returns ["he-IL", "en-US", "en", "he"], and English is set as a default. Well I did ended up deleting Hebrew completely to fix this. Just wondered if I were doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, it's set to the default language of your browser, navigator is a read-only object which displays our browser properties. Did you try adding Hebrew again, then we can check whether English is default or Hebrew overwrites English as default. (If it's latter you still can replicate the procedure you did)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I landed on this page...

It seems that even if a language is set as default, navigator.language will return always the first language on the list.

You can easily reorder your list of used languages and put your "default language" on first position. ;-)